# Recover secondary drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive-recovery, ext4, filesystem-corruption

I haven't been able to mount my secondary hard drive, and I am unsure as to the error. This happens when I try mounting through Nautilus:

[image: error code it throws when I try mounting through Nautilus]

I tried `sudo fsck.ext4 -y /dev/sdb1` and `sudo fsck /dev/sdb` but so far nothing's worked.

The output from `sudo file -s /dev/sdb /dev/sdb1`:

```
/dev/sdb:  x86 boot sector
/dev/sdb1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=57a97877-0fc2-467b-84e5-1b94a520f10f, volume name "STORAGE" (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)
```

How to fix this? How to make the filesystem fully operational again?

Comment: Which file system does this external drive use? If it is exFAT or HFS(+) you might need to install the relevant utilities.

Comment: Did `fsck.ext4 /dev/sdb1` give you any feedback? What was it?

Comment: Sorry about being away for so long, I got sidetracked and eventually forgot about this issue. I got `fsck.ext4: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdb1
Could this be a zero-length partition?`